# Dynamic directive controller using name property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to implement directive with dynamic controller so that I can bind controller based on some condition just like Todd Motto has shown it [here](https://toddmotto.com/dynamic-controllers-in-directives-with-the-undocumented-name-property/)

Everything works fine expect that I can't send object property as a name to the directive like,

```
<directive-with-dynamic-controller ctrl="someObj.prop"></directive-with-dynamic-controller>
```

I've even tried this, but to no avail:

```
<directive-with-dynamic-controller ctrl="{{someObj.prop}}"></directive-with-dynamic-controller>
```

It gives error like this:

> Argument is not a function, got undefined

Any ideas how I can solve this? Or any other way?
Thanks!

Comment: what is the structure of `someObj`?

Comment: someObj = {"type": "someValue"}

Comment: that's not really helpful. your controller should be a function. is `someObj.prop` a function?

Comment: Hi @yarons,
As per Todd Motto's article, you pass a string to ctrl attribute in directive and that string should be a name of the controller function that will be bound to the directive.

Comment: You should post your own code in your question

Comment: I think posting your own code isn't necessary. Conveying the problem is, which I've done.

Comment: Code isn't really necessary in this case as it has nothing to do with the structure of the given object. It has to do with DOM compilation and the order of execution behind the scenes in Angular. The mentioned article fails to mention the limitations of this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any ideas how I can solve this? Or any other way? Thanks!

The problem is in the order of execution. Something that was left out in the mentioned article is the fact that you *cannot* pass an expression in the case of setting a "dynamic" controller (so much for dynamic).

If we look at the notation of a directives *compile* step, you would notice that there is **no** access to the current `$scope`.

This is because DOM compilation and controller initialisation happens **before** the angular parser kicks in and evaluates your expression(s).

As such, you **cannot** pass a $scope expression into the `ctrl` attribute, as it is simply a regular DOM attribute at this point in time. In essence, you are passing the **raw** string into the `ctrl` attribute.

```
<my-custom-dir ctrl="foo.bar"></my-custom-dir>

// Error: "foo.bar" is not a controller // is not a function // $minErrObscureStuffThatDoesnHelpYou.
```

I've been trying to figure out a slick way to get [deferred directive compilation](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2095) running for some time now, but to no avail...

One *possible way* of getting around this problem (**ymmv**):

```
.directive('...', function ($controller) {
  controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
    $attrs.$observe('ctrl', function (n, o) {
      return $controller(n, {
        $scope:   $scope,
        $element: $element,
        $attrs:   $attrs
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Effectively, you would *replace* a pre-initialised controller (that does nothing) with the controller matched by the name you passed through your `attrs.ctrl` attribute. However, this would execute post-compilation - so I wouldn't seriously recommend it.

[jsfiddle showing the order of execution](https://jsfiddle.net/oms48mu9/1/)

**tl;dr** There is currently no slick way to define a controller for a directive, based on a $scope expression. It has to be a raw string because compilation isn't scoped on a per-component basis, but more so in a 'global' order of execution.

> DOM Compilation > Controller initialisation > Scope linkage [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9erp8j6z/)

Comment: Hey Kasper, thanks for the explaining it properly. This could have been a efficient way to attach controller dynamically to directives but angular architecture design prevents it.